# getDefaultGcsBucketName Response contained no data

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to call AppIdentityService#getDefaultGcsBucketName but it throws an exception: Response contained no data. According to the docs, the default bucket should be ready to use. Code:

```
//Field
private AppIdentityService service;

//in ctor
this.service = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

//call inside a method
final String baseUrl = GCS_URL + "/" + service.getDefaultGcsBucketName() + "/" + fileName;
```

Comment: Can you upload data the default bucket using the cloudstorage console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your app prior to the 1.9.0 SDK release, you have to manually setup your default GCS bucket. Read [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/setup) for more information (I know its for PHP, but its applicable across all languages).

Comment: The application is created with 1.8.x. I tried to create the default according to your guide, but I get the message "This bucket you tried to create requires domain ownership verification".

Comment: Did you try to do so by "clicking Create within the Cloud Integration section in the Application Settings page of the App Engine Admin Console." method? If you try to make it manually I don't think it will work as you don't own the appspot.com domain.

Comment: No, I tried to create a bucket with the name but that didn't work. I read somewhere that google will over time bring this feature to older apps, but who knows. We stick with a custom bucket atm.

Comment: It should work if you press that button, otherwise you can open a support ticket if you pay for support. I myself use a custom bucket as well and I think that you can better organize your app and its assets that way. Different buckets to organize different kinds of objects you plan to hold (e.g. logs, datastore blobs, pictures, static content, etc.)