# getDefaultGcsBucketName contained no data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using app engine 1.9.7 sdk and attempting to follow the documentation on Google Cloud Storage client access. i'm trying to find the default bucket name (so i can test things out with the free quota). 2 questions though:

1) whenever i try to use

```
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
String bucketName = appIdentity.getDefaultGcsBucketName();

resp.getWriter().println("no write " + bucketName);
```

i get this exception:

> Uncaught exception from servlet com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException:
>   getDefaultGcsBucketNameResponse contained no data     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getDefaultGcsBucketName(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:163)

why does it not contain data?

2) i accidentally activated and created a new bucket (and wrote a very small file to it). how come the charge isn't showing up on my monthly estimated charges?

i have the same problem as this guy: "[getDefaultGcsBucketName Response contained no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912216/getdefaultgcsbucketname-response-contained-no-data)" but the problem is that i'm using a later version of app engine

Comment: Is your Appengine pre 1.9.0? If so, you likely don't have a default bucket. You can create one by clicking Create within the Cloud Integration section in the Application Settings page of the App Engine Admin Console.

Comment: nope, unfortunately i'm using 1.9.7     :'( do you know how to do it after 1.9.0?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with an 1.9.7 app. Go to [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com), go to *Administration-> Application Settings*. Scroll to the bottom of the page, Cloud Integration and enable it.

After a while you should see the Google Cloud Storage Bucket, in the "Basics" field in the same page.

Comment: @tashuhka Hi, I see that you are making a large number of edits, I just wanted to give you a friendly heads up that normally very small edits to formatting are not encouraged on this site unless they fix something substantial about the post, the reason for this is that several high rep users must review your edit. Please try and make your edits a bit more substantial and less frequent to help the quality of the site and not make quite so much work for edit reviewers. Many thanks.

Comment: @Vality. Of course! Thank you for the friendly advice.

Comment: Thanks. Strange how it isn't activated automatically which the documentation suggests https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/activate#Using_the_Default_GCS_Bucket